# How can I unsubscribe in an class extending Application?

Tags: android, rx-java

I have the have following code :

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        doBackgroundStuffOnLaunch();
    }

    private void doBackgroundStuffOnLaunch() {
        Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void call(Subscriber<? super Boolean> subscriber) {
                // read a file or any other background operation
                subscriber.onNext(isItPossibleToReadTheFile());
                subscriber.onCompleted();
            }
        })
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(new DoStuffDependingOnTheResultSubscriber());
    }
}
```

I am wondering, whether I should attempt to unsubscribe the DoStuffDependingOnTheResultSubscriber in case user exits the application before the background work is finished (and if I should, what method should it be?). Or perhaps calling onCompleted on it is enough, and it will not leak now.

Or perhaps the approach is completely wrong, and I should never use rx observables in application class.

Should I always try to call unsubscribe on Subscriptions that's subscribers have finished their work ?

Comment: I am not feeling sure enough about this to post it as an actual answer but: I don't think it is actually possible to *leak* an `Application`. The instance will be created when the process for your app is created and will be destroyed when the process is finished. In between these two points the Application will just continue to exist as part of the process and no second instance will ever be created. Thus it is not possible to *leak* that instance in the sense that it stays around when it should already be garbage collected...

Comment: However, you may want to keep to a minimum the stuff you are doing in your `Application` class while the app is not "in the foreground"...